# Password protect Grub2, but still allow normal boot

Tags: linux-mint, boot, grub2, grub, boot-loader

I have seen this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370693/how-to-add-the-grub-password-protection-to-the-os-load-process-instead-of-when-e)  , but I don't have `grub.conf` in the first place. His situation is the inverse from mine though.

This [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords)  explains quite a fair bit on Grub2, but I am still clueless as to how to do it. I am not technical-savvy enough I guess..

I am using LinuxMint 16.

Everything that I have tried so far still requires a password for booting. I want a password to be requested only when a user is trying to edit the boot options.

Answer (score 1):

just add "--unrestricted" to the "class" line in /etc/grub.d/10_linux as described here: 
 https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=840204#c53

 then regenerate your grub config with "grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg" or whatever is appropriate for your install.

if you already have your password setup prior to this you will now have the grub config you were seeking.
This seems to be an issue/regression with the upstream grub project and not so much fedora as i'm using arch and i had the same problem. neither the arch wiki nor the grub docs really address this situation, as far as i could tell.

I'm guessing i'll need to backup my /etc/grub.d/10_linux and/or set it as immutable so that maybe it will break grub updates as a reminder as to what i've done, until this is fixed upstream.

Answer (score 1):

You should not add but replace the `--users` with the `--unrestricted`:

```
sudo vim /etc/grub.d/10_linux +127
   echo "menuentry '$(echo "$title" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} --unrestricted  '' \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-$version-$type-$boot_device_id' {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  else
      echo "menuentry '$(echo "$os" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} --unrestricted  '' \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-$boot_device_id' {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"

sudo update-grub
```

**kubuntu14.04 example shown